# Visual Studio 2017 issue at startup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am facing an issue every time I open the VS, an error message appears and I have to restart it in order to work correctly.

[image]

Comment: Does the XML file it refers to have any useful information?

Comment: Otherwise, [Problems when starting VS 2017 Enterprise on Windows 10](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30312/problems-when-starting-vs-2017-enterprise-on-windo.html).